# Logical equivalence reasoning same letters

Tags: logic

Why is it that when p<=>p = T?

P <=> q means " p if and only if q". Does this mean when you draw out the table of possibilities, you make p=q so:

### p q p <=> q

### T T    T

### T F    F

### F T    F

### F F    T

So now I make p=q it means that

### p p  p <=> p

### T T     T

### F F     T

Is this reasoning correct for why p <=> p = T ? If it is not, please explain why

Thank you.

Comment: The second row should be FFT

Comment: Does this mean with that changed bit, my reasoning for why when p is logically equivalent to p is correct?   @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: Yes, that is indeed why!

Comment: Usually, you would have only one column of input for the single variable $p$ in your second truth table.

Comment: See [Truth table for $\leftrightarrow$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_equality)